# Why are my builds not showing up in Itunes Connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

It's my first app, and I've finished it yesterday. I've "finished it" a few times for the past months, and archived it all those times, but none of them appeared in Itunes Connect, plus I added more features. But now I'm sure it's done.
I have a paid apple developer account, developing and distribution certificates (installed too), an app group for the app, an app provisoning profile for both distribution and development, all set in Xcode too, everything ready and set to distribute it. I've also already created the app in Itunes Connect and filled in all the information, screenshots, etc. I just need the freakin' build to appear in freakin' Itunes Connect, god dammit! I validate it, upload it to the App Store, reload the Itunes Connect page and.... NOTHING appears! I know that it's not instantaneous, so I wait for 24 hours, and.... nothing appears. Something is wrong. I think it has to deal with the archives I made a month ago, when I didn't know much about submitting an app, and I didn't have many things set.... And no, I didn't incremented the Version nor Build number when I archived again. Yesterday I archived it again, checked today, nothing appeared. Now, I've changed the build number to 2, and archived it again, 30 minutes ago, I'm still waiting for a build to appear, but I don't think it will!!! Would someone please help me? That's the last step for me to submit the app, cause all the rest is done.

Comment: You've verified you're using the same developer account to validate, archive, upload, and sign into iTC?

Comment: when you submit you app you got successful notification?

Comment: Yeah, I do get it!

Comment: in your iTunes connect account go to Prepare for Submission,got to Build section are you see + sign ?

Comment: No, there's no + sign

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must archived your app and submit it to store, if you submit it right you will get message like [image]

after it you will wait for few mints to see plus sign in iTunes connect like [image]
by clicked + sign you will get you version.
if your app take a lot of time in processing, may be more than one week,
Go to "Resources & Help" in iTunes Connect. Select "Contact Us" and follow the wizard. I don't think anyone other than Apple can answer this. And this is what we have done in a similar situation in the past.

Comment: I don't get this + sign, nor the build stated as "Processing", that's the thing.

Comment: @HenriqueDourado Be patient, initial processing takes time.

Comment: yeah it may be take a lot of time, look to my answer update

Comment: @matt Are you saying that it takes time to even appear the build saying that it's processing? I thought that it was instantly. Like, submitted, and boom: "Processing". I'll wait till tomorrow then.

Comment: You don't see the + in iTunes Connect until you get the email from Apple that the processing is complete. This changed somewhat recently where in the past you saw the + immediately (with processing next to the build).

Comment: You should contact Apple, processing should not take more than a few minutes. There seems to be a bug where the build processes then disappears from the activity page. I am also dealing with this problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

Add a .pch file in your project an

```
#import <Availability.h>
#ifndef __IPHONE_8_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 8.0 and later."
#endif
```

Using application loader deploy to iTunes

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

To anyone still encountering this problem, it may be because your Xcode isn't updated to the latest version.

To find out if you need to update, go to App Store Connect -> your app -> Activity -> and look for "see supported versions". You will see a list of supported versions there

[image]